# Upgrade python 3.4 to 3.5 (latest) in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04

How to upgrade Python 3.4 to the latest version available on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: [How do I update Python from 3.4.3 to 3.5?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/680824/how-do-i-update-python-from-3-4-3-to-3-5)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding an additional installation and not actually upgrading the `python3` binary past where ubuntu expects it. Anything system use of python that depends on python3.4 but breaks under 3.5, will make your life tough.

[pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) is nice tool for maintaining multiple local versions of python but it'll almost certainly replace virtualenv in your workflow.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do it, in my opinion, is using [ANACONDA](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). Very, very convenient.